# ExtJs - Textfield with dynamic closeable labels

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am using ExtJS 4 and I need to implement something similar to the closable labels that you get in GMail when typing an email address in a textfield (see screenshot below). I've been reviewing the ExtJS library and the closest I see to this is to provide some type of layout with custom closable panels or to use CellEditing with a grid, but I still haven't seen a way to do it with a textfield.

So my question is, am I in the right track or is there another component I should consider that would be more suitable for the job? Additionally, if somebody could point or provide a code example with something closer what I have in the screenshot then that would be also very helpful.

[image: GMail - Email Labels]

Comment: Ext 5 introduced the tag field, which is exactly what you describe. You could look at upgrading, or possibly trying to backport that component.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli As far as I know, the tagfield does not allow to add new tags by typing, only to select from the existing tags.

Comment: It does allow you to do that, it extends combo box: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Tag-cfg-createNewOnEnter, http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Tag-cfg-createNewOnBlur

Comment: @EvanTrimboli, thanks for the suggestion but upgrading to ExtJs5 is not an option right now, as suggested in one of the answers BoxSelect is a better alternative in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are on ExtJS 4, You should look into [BoxSelect](https://github.com/kveeiv/extjs-boxselect).

Here and there you may need to make necessary customizations. But high-level this is pretty decent field for inputing tags for Ext-4.

In-fact the Tag field in ExtJS5 is inspired by BoxSelect.